# How to develop a ruby-on-rails application across multiple domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, view

Im rather new to Rails, but one of my clients plans to operate multiple *very similar* web platforms on different domains, which means most of the source/application code is identical (e.g. models/controllers). However, there could be some minor code changes or additions for the certain applications. If that circumstance is hard to achieve, *at least* the CSS files/images/views will be different though.

What's a good way to deal with this issue? Excluding the mentioned (different) files in the deployment and add them manually where needed? Though, this cannot really be the best solution?!

I'd obviously love to avoid copying and modifying the same project several times (per web application).

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it has less to do with Rails and more with the way you keep your code versioned.

Firstly, I'd suggest you to use a distributed version control system (I recommend Git), then keep the common code in a branch (i.e. master), and create at least one branch per domain.

http://book.git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Rails Engine](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) for your core functionality. Then create separate rails applications that use your engine. Within each application, you should be able to override the bits that need customization or add additional functionality to the app.